# Rvest returns error "Empty reply from the server" when using Last.fm web API

Tags: r, last.fm, rvest

Ok, so what I am trying to do is to get a list of top tags for an artist from Last.FM web API by parsing XML file it returns for my request using rvest.

However, when I am trying to get contents of the XML, I get this error:

```
html("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getTopTags&artist=artistname&api_key=apikey")

Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Empty reply from server
```

I tried using different functions from different packages for parsing (getURL, readWeb), but all artist.get methods return empty reply. However, accessing that very URL for API request in browser works just fine. Also, user.get methods work just as fine.

What might cause this? Do I have to look for troubles on my side? Is it rvest? Last.FM?

Comment: Who knows... `api_key <- "..."; rvest::html(paste0("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.gettoptags&artist=radiohead&album=the%20bends&api_key=", api_key))` works fine, here. Maybe proxy settings?

Comment: Might be, where are you situated though? Perhaps some licensing issues here, I'll try using proxy servers anyway, thanks for the idea.

Comment: No proxy. I use R version 3.1.1 on x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 with package versions httr_0.5, rvest_0.1, XML_3.98-1.1, RCurl_1.95-4.3.

Comment: for what it's worth, I just had the same issue - but I'm trying to pull in a fair amount of data in to R.  23.5 gb.